# Cant extract variable data into a string format for passing to a db

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Currently I have all the following held within a variable.(badgeselected). Which returns the following in console.log

```
[<img id=​"go" src=​"http:​/​/​kudosoo.com/​Pics/​Lisa_Wong.jpg" alt=​"img" style=​"cursor:​ pointer;​">​ , <div id=​"go">​</div>​  ]
```

Using js/juery I'd like to extract just the url so I can store it in a db as a string

How can I do this? At the moment I have the variable defined as the following, but I'm not sure if .val is correct to turn it into a string?

```
var badgeselected = $("#badge").val();
```

Comment: `$("#badge img").attr('src');`

Comment: THanks guys, not sure which is the best option..but happy to accept @Runner response as the answer as it was the first reply

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just do this

```
$("#badge").attr("src")
```